# Railsチュートリアル第7章

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

[Railsチュートリアル第7章](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/sign_up?version=4.2#cha-sign_up)が全て終わり`rails s`では問題なく登録できたのですが、 
`heroku push`の後の`heroku open`で問題が発生しました。 
`http://localhost:3000/`の画面は問題なく表示されたのですが 
sign up now!と入力すると

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong. 
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

と表示されました。

`heroku logs`で調べて問題がありそうなところをピックアップしてみました。 
具体的にどうすればいいか分からず悩んでいます。具体的な解決方法を教えてください。

```
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist 
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass 
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), 
pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod 
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d 
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum 
WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass 
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped 
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 1):

db:migrateを実行してテーブルを作成すれば直るのではないでしょうか。

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: コマンドを入力してテーブル作成もしたのですがどうも上手くいきませんでした。丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: エラーのスタックトレース全体を追記してもらえると原因がわかるかもしれません。